# Node.js glob - matching a path under any directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, gulp, glob

With node.js globbing, I want to match some path, under any subdirectory. I hope my code example is clearer than my wording:

`app/themes/*/images/icons/**/*.png`

So, imagine the following:

```
app
|-- themes
|   |-- theme1
|   |   `-- images
|   |       `-- icons
|   |           `-- home-icon.png
|   `-- theme2
|       `-- images
|           `-- icons
|               `-- home-icon.png
```

It should match both `home-icon.png`s, in both **theme1** and **theme2**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`app/themes/*/images/icons/*.png`

Code to try in Node console

```
var g = require('glob');
g('app/themes/*/images/icons/*.png', function (er, files) {
    console.log(files);
});
```

Should list the files that match

Comment: Thanks. And what if I want to recursively match *anything under `images/`* too?

Comment: to match any directory under images, `app/themes/*/images/**/*.png`

Comment: Thanks, I am checking it now, will report in a minute.

Comment: It works! That's what I tried before but it didn't work for me with any Grunttask... I will have to run some tests again. Thanks.